# Difference between DNS spoofing and phishing

Tags: dns, phishing, spoofing

I am writing a bachelor thesis and I am having a hard time figuring out the difference between phishing and DNS spoofing. From what I understand, DNS spoofing is a way to achieve a succesfull phishing of somebody's user name and passwords (or other credentials).

Do I understand it correctly ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Phishing is a broad topic and DNS Spoofing is a tactic that can be used for phishing. But you identify that. What is your confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phishing is mostly a social attack, i.e. you might setup up a site which looks like a trusted one (i.e. copy of Paypal), give it a hostname which might fool the user (e.g. https-paypal.encrypted.whatever) so that the URL and links look trustable, put it together with some story ("detected hacking attempt, needs verification..") in a mail and wait for gullible users. You might use it to get credentials, infect the user with malware etc.

DNS spoofing instead is a technical attack, where the attacker tries to respond to a DNS query ("get me the IP address for paypal.com") with their own (wrong) answer and thus direct the user to the attackers site instead of the requested site.

Since DNS spoofing is a technical attack you can protect against it with technical solutions, like DNSSec. Using https also protects against DNS spoofing since the attacker does not has the certificate for the requested name. None of these things help against pishing, since this attack is not against a technical based trust system but against a social trust system. Against phishing, only awareness helps, and if you are lucky the phishing attack was not targeted against you, but against lots of users. In which case browsers often have the relevant sites in a blacklist already.

Answer (score 2):

Phishing is a way of getting credentials by manipulating the victim in some way to give his credentials. An example will be a fake login page.

DNS spoofing is a method to alter the DNS information and bringing victim to your personalized server or not letting him access the website completely. It's one application is used in a variant of evil twin attack.